# Side by side divs

Tags: css

If you had a look at this forum http://python-forum.org/pythonforum/, you could notice that borders which Topics and Posts divs have are short. I am writting a forum and now have a problem with blocks which must go side by side (just like those four at the above mentioned forum). Could you please help me arrange four blocks side by side so that my forum wouldn't have that sort of shortness.

Comment: Could you give some further information?
Maybe a screenshot with some arrows could help.
I just don't get what you mean by short.

Comment: Please look at this http://savepic.ru/834672.png

Answer (score 2):

You should use tables.

There are only a few cases in which the use of a table is allowed (if you go by the semantic html rules), and this is one. The overview of forums, amount of posts and views, last poster, etc is a set of tabular data. It's safe and perfectly acceptable to use tables.

The <dl> element however was not intended to be used in this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSS style of the `<dd>` element that you are requesting:

```
UL.topiclist DD 
{   
  PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;   
  DISPLAY: block;   
  PADDING-LEFT: 0px;    
  FLOAT: left;  
  PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px;  
  BORDER-LEFT: #ffffff 1px solid;   
  PADDING-TOP: 4px
}
```

The important one to get it side by side is `FLOAT: left;`.

The short vertical line, is just the `border-left`.

Comment: i recommend `display:inline` on your floats. (This will be essentially ignored, as floats are implicitly blocks.) This is for the benefit of IE; otherwise you'll get the double-margin bug. http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/floatIndent.html

Comment: @awe: yes, the short vertical line is a border-left. and it's short.

Comment: @Sweetie: If you wonder why it's short, it's just that the `<dd>` element is not in the full height of the "row". You should look at the html source to see how it is done.

Comment: Yeah, how to get it to be full height in that case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want two divs to be side-by-side, you could try using inline-block:

```
<style>
    #div1, #div2 {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```